# Discrete slider в Material Design

Tags: android, android-studio, material-design

Можно ли вместо обычного слайдера в android выбрать другой (с числовым значением, как на пикче)?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это с  [оф. ресурса](http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/sliders.html#sliders-discrete-slider) по material design. Там говорится про обычный слайдер, который стоит базовым в android studio и такой с числовым значением. Или они просто, как пример, его там показали?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это просто гайдлайны по Material Design. Они относятся не к Андроиду, а к дизайну в общем. Кроме того, такого класса, как Slider в Андроид нету. Аналог называется SeekBar. Можете попробовать сделать для него тему (маловероятно, что такое возможно), или сделать на его основе свой класс, который будет похож на то, что на картинке